# Synchronize two iframes mouse actions with JQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, onclick, jquery-events

What I need to do is to synchronize two `iframe` elements with every mouse action.
I have a window with two identical `iframe` elements and if for example I am clicking on a button in the first `iframe` I want the "twin" button in the second `iframe` also to be clicked.

Lets assume that I do not have access to the website which is inside the `iframe` but it is on the same domain as the parent site. Is it doable using only jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I'd pressume you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ptsrszbr/1/

When you click button1, it triggers button2.

so I guess were you to specify which button you clicked, I think it could be done like this:

```
$('.Iframe1 .button1').on('click', function(){
  $('.Iframe2 .button1').trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't know whats gonna be on that page. I would rather a solution that would allow me to catch a mouse event from one iframe and reproduce it in the second one on the same position.

Comment: hmm alright, I'm going to try to make that. please don't assume that I will succeed cause I'm a jQuery scrub too. I just like helping people. haha

Comment: welp, I tried. https://jsfiddle.net/ptsrszbr/16/ I got that far I'm sorry man x) I hope someone else will be able to help you. goodluck :)